# JasperReports: Embedded reports call stalls intermittently

Tags: javascript, jasper-reports, jasperserver

We have an application running on AngularJS front end and JasperReports integrated using the Visualize.js embedding framework.

We do frequently see an intermittent issue in all web browsers where JasperReports's reports show blank from time to time. I would like to add that we are making 8 different calls to get the reports; one call per report.

Sometimes, all reports are showing blank while other times few reports out of 8 are displayed properly. It appears that the call to get the report will stall in the browser; however, all the other calls made before work just fine.

At the moment the issue is happening, no errors are displayed in the logs, CPU and memory usage are low but when looking at the audit report, the reportExecutionTime of failing reports (the one showing blank) is very high; it reaches more than 900s. Has anyone experienced that before? If yes, please advice on how to solve it.

Comment: Are you talking about custom application or about JasperReports Server?

Comment: We run reports in JasperReports Server and display them in a custom application using visualize.js

Comment: Any answer to share about this issue?